# Matplotlib color point with rgba-value Python :O

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, rgb

I already have a plot of some data for which I use `contourf` and `cm.jet` as my colormap. `vmin`=-100 and `vmax`= 100

I read in another question that I can access a specific color from my colormap with `cm.jet(x)`, where x is in [0,1].

I want to get the color for 47 so I thought I try it with

```
 fortyseven=pylab.cm.jet(0.735)
```

This would return me the **rgb value** of 47.

Then I wanted to plot a point with this specific rgb value:

```
ax.plot( x, y, fortyseven)
```

But this won't work out. I always get an

```
ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

error.

So I tried it with

```
 ax.plot( x, y, 'fortyseven')
```

and I get an

```
ValueError: Unrecognized character f in format string
```

error.

So is it even possible to color a point with a rgb value?

Or do I overlook something?

**EDIT**

Would it work if I convert the **rgb-value** to **hex-value** ?

**EDIT**

I just realised that it will return a **rgba-value**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just use the `color` keyword in your `plot` command, which accepts any `matplotlib` color, including an `RGBA tuple`, which is what `cm.jet(0.735)` returns.

```
ax.plot(x, y, color = fortyseven)
```

Comment: Perfect thats exactly what I wanted to know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did some research and now can answer my own questions.

Actually the alpha in rgba stands for transparency so it doesn't affect the color itself only how opaque it is.

So basically you can just cut the alpha value away and it doesn't change the color itself.

There is even a Python-function `to_rgb` which exactlyu does that.

The description:

```
to_rgb(arg)

Returns an RGB tuple of three floats from 0-1.

arg can be an RGB or RGBA sequence or a string in any of several forms:

   a letter from the set ‘rgbcmykw’
   a hex color string, like ‘#00FFFF’
   a standard name, like ‘aqua’
   a string representation of a float, like ‘0.4’, indicating gray on a 0-1 scale

if arg is RGBA, the A will simply be discarded.
```

So now I can work with the **rgb-value** and plot my point.